Does aws/aliyun instance running on a fixed physical machine, or the instance may migrate from one physical machine to another?
For the aws EC2 and aliyun instances or other similar cloud computing services, is the VM guaranteed to run on the same physical machine each time you launch it, or it may migrate from one physical machine to another?
Also I know hypervisors support live migration, so is it possible that my running aws/aliyun instance migrated by the service provider, which may cause a short time outage or unresponsiveness.
Here is the reason for my question: I have a aliyun server collecting realtime data packets stream from another aws server. Each packet has a sender timestamp tag. At the receiver side, receiver uses the (current_local_timestamp - sender_timestamp) to get the elapsed time. Usually this elapsed time is around 30~50ms, sometimes ~100ms. But in the extreme cases, this elapsed time can go up to a few seconds or even more than 1 minutes, this case happens at least 2~3 times a month, often at Friday (but not always) or some holidays.
I'm trying to figuring out the reason for the extreme large transport delay.

"is the VM guaranteed to run on the same physical machine each time you launch it"
Nope. In fact, on AWS specifically (at the time that question was asked and answered) it says it's very unlikely to be the same host.
What problem are you trying to solve?
Per your edits - live migration should not cause up-to-1-minute lags. That's very unlikely to be the cause of your problem.

Thank you for your answer. I have updated my quesiton add the reason for my question. I'm trying to figure out the cause for the extremely delayed networking communication issue that occasionally happend to my aliy/aws servers. I think the issue is caused by the aliyun side, and I suspect that my running aliyun VM is physically migrated.

Ive edited my answer to reflect your new question
